# Difference between sending EOS to pipeline vs source elements

Tags: c++, video-streaming, media-player, gstreamer

Can someone clarify what exactly happens when an EOS is sent directly to the GstElement representing the pipeline (GstBin)?

I've had a pipeline with multiple source branches (audio & video) going into a mp4mux, and I've found in certain cases I have to send an EOS directly to both audio & video source elements for proper EOS propagation, as opposed to sending an EOS to the entire pipeline.

Comment: Why are you sending an EOS event? This is something that should come from a source element (or maybe something like a demuxer), not from the application. Maybe you're trying to stop the pipeline? Than you should be setting it to GST_STATE_NULL.

Comment: @nielsdg , From my understanding, when saving video files, you generally want to send an EOS down the pipeline to flush out the individual elements and specifically the filesink element. If you set them to NULL before the EOS, the video file will likely not be playable